# Audit events in Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure

When making changes to Containers, File Shares, Queues, Tables in a Storage Account, no audit of it is shown in the "Audit logs" section.

Is there a flag/setting that enables audit log tracing for Storage Accounts?

Example audit log, after making numerous actions in the Storage Account, by UI and by CLI:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When making changes to Containers, File Shares, Queues, Tables in a
>   Storage Account, no audit of it is shown in the "Audit logs" section.

This is expected behavior. `Activity Logs` (formerly known as `Audit Logs`) logs activities that has happened over `control plane` which includes operations like creation/deletion of storage accounts, regeneration of account keys etc. Creation/updation/deletion of blob containers, tables, shares etc. come under `data plane` which are not captured by these logs. To see these activities, you would need to make use of [`Storage Analytics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343270.aspx) especially [`Storage Analytics Logs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343262.aspx).

> Is there a flag/setting that enables audit log tracing for Storage
>   Accounts?

No. You need to make use of `Storage Analytics Logs` to see these activities.

Comment: Thank you!
This is a goldmine :)

Comment: @Guarav Mantri
Do you know if creation of a queue, a message in it, deletion of a message, clearing of a queue, or a table should show in these logs?
So far I've only received events such as ListBlobs, GetBlob, GetBlobProperties, same for Queue - never the actions that mean something, only actions of view made from the portal.

Comment: Yes, these events should be there. What gets logged by storage analytics is based on how you have configured it.

Comment: I've configured them all to log all: https://imagebin.ca/v/2unvlrjL5qD5

Comment: The settings looks ok to me. The events should be there in blobs in `$logs` blob container. How are you viewing the contents of these files?

Comment: it seems I'm now receiving most of the logs - it was just a delay on ~3 hours between the generation of the events until is it in the logs.
Most of them anyways - still not getting events of creation/deletion of the queues, tables, blobs, only the actions made within them (e.g. adding a message to a queue).  
btw, I'm reading the events via the Azure Java SDK, and generating actions via both the azure CLI and the Java SDK.